# Как получить данные с тега?

Tags: php, phpquery

Делаю запрос:

```
$url = file_get_contents('http://mysite.com);
$getHtml = phpQuery::newDocument($url);
$doc = $results->find('.row > .row.text-center p')->contents();
```

Когда вывожу:

```
echo $doc;
```

Получаю html в видe:

```
<p>значение</p> <p>значение</p> <p>значение</p>
```

Как мне получить данные с тега ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        foreach ($doc as $item) {
        $result[] = pq($item)->html();
    }
```